# CSS How to position select box options grid to left?

Tags: css, css-selectors

My code belove

https://jeremi.w3spaces.com/button_css.html

Problem is if I add padding to select box making select box blue and touch friendly the options listbox is not aligned properly. Listbox maintains relative position to the select box without padding. I want to move the listbox to left 20px so that it's postion is aligned with padding.

Edit code to expand and make button colorfull:

```
select {
  #display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
  padding: 15px 5px 15px 15px;
  border: none;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  min-width: 150px;
  #border-color: DodgerBlue;
  /*Muokataan nuoli kaikissa selaimissa*/   
  #appearance: none;
  #-moz-appearance: none;
  #-webkit-appearance: none;  
  #&::-ms-expand { display: none };  
 }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this. I move padding off from div and to select box native define so it resized selectbox natively acording with padding.